# Different usage of <PAD>, <EOS> and <GO> tokens

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I found that there are many different usages of `<PAD>`, `<EOS>`, and `<GO>` tokens.

Personally, I separate those three tokens and assign different embeddings to them, assigning an all-zero embedding vector to `<PAD>` token specifically (with RNN-based seq2seq model).

The majority of codes show that `<PAD>`, `<EOS>` and `<GO>` are all represented as `<PAD>` token.

I want to know if there is the optimum usage of those tokens (in terms of RNN-based models or transformer-based models).

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of this one https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26947/why-do-we-need-to-add-start-s-end-s-symbols-when-using-recurrent-neural-n

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist That one is asking about the role of each token while my question is about the empirical conclusion about the optimal usage of them

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "optimal." The answer is that yes for seq2seq modeling you should use <SOS>, <EOS> and <PAD> where applicable. They should each have their own embedding as they are distinct tokens.

Comment: I know that they have each has its own role and also I am using them separately, however, I found many seq2seq-related codes from github are only using <PAD> instead of using all of them (many of google's also do). I'm curious about the effect of substituting three tokens to one <PAD> token, even it makes a tiny improvement to the performance of the model.

Answer (score 0):

These are the special tokens used in seq2seq:

GO - the same as  on the picture below - the first token which is fed to the decoder along with the though vector in order to start generating tokens of the answer
EOS - "end of sentence" - the same as  on the picture below - as soon as decoder generates this token we consider the answer to be complete (you can't use usual punctuation marks for this purpose cause their meaning can be different)
UNK - "unknown token" - is used to replace the rare words that did not fit in your vocabulary. So your sentence My name is guotong1988 will be translated into My name is *unk*.
PAD - your GPU (or CPU at worst) processes your training data in batches and all the sequences in your batch should have the same length. If the max length of your sequence is 8, your sentence My name is guotong1988 will be padded from either side to fit this length: My name is guotong1988 *pad* *pad* *pad* *pad*

[will help understand better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQmGa.png)

Reference: https://github.com/nicolas-ivanov/tf_seq2seq_chatbot/issues/15